# cannot use Room database kotlin

Tags: android, database, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I cannot use `@Entity`, `@Dao`, `@Database`.
Error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WLD7.png)

This is my implementation :

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0-alpha01'


implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0'

compile 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
compile 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
compile 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
```

I don't know where to fix it.
I already have plugin kapt.

Comment: You've got `androidx.room:room-runtime` twice for 2.4.2 and for 2.5.01-alpha01

Comment: i delete it and nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to upgrade room annotation library from kapt to ksp.

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2" 
to
ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
```